# Which is the best entry type in BibLaTeX to cite an article of a conference published in a Journal

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I would like to cite a paper from a conference proceedings. The proceedings has been published as a special issue of a journal. Which is the best entry type, `@article` or `@inproceeding`, to use in this case?

`@inproceeding` allows to add data about the event; that I would like to inlcude, but then I don't where to put the journal name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely `@article`. "Special issues" of journals are commonplace. Many journals let more than 50% of their issues be "special" in that sense. The main point of a bibliography is to aid your readers in locating the entries. Since you will always find the "special issues" of a journal together with the other issues of the journal (either physically in a library or online), you should list them as issues of that journal. If necessary, use the field `issuetitle` (or `issuesubtitle`/`addendum`/`note`) under `@article` to put in whatever the issue says about it being "special".

Answer (score 1):

`@Inproceedings` is the way to go. Is the journal name not (part of) the `booktitle`?  Otherwise there's the `series` field, but it might not be passed to the document, depending on your bibliography style.